# How to get captions of actual windows currently running?

Tags: windows, delphi, list, captions

I have a question: I simply need to get captions of all windows in a list, by captions I mean the "Notepad", "Total Commander" - simply the text shown in the top-edge of a window.

So far I've gotten here

```
function EnumWindowProc(hHwnd: HWND; lParam : integer): boolean; stdcall;
var
  pPid : DWORD;
  title, ClassName : string;
begin
  if (hHwnd=NULL) then
  begin
    result := false;
  end
  else
  begin
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hHwnd,pPid);
    SetLength(ClassName, 255);
    SetLength(ClassName,
              GetClassName(hHwnd,
                           PChar(className),
                           Length(className)));
    SetLength(title, 255);
    SetLength(title, GetWindowText(hHwnd, PChar(title), Length(title)));
    OptionsForm.ListBox1.Items.Add(title);
    OptionsForm.Memo1.Lines.Add
      ('Class Name = ' + className +
       '; Title = ' + title +
       '; HWND = ' + IntToStr(hHwnd) +
       '; Pid = ' + IntToStr(pPid));
    Result := true;
  end;
end;
```

But well, it returns all kinds of "windows", different focuses of forms etc. How can I get only the "main" ones?

Here is a sample of the results:

```
Class Name = Shell_TrayWnd; Title = ; HWND = 65898; Pid = 3776
Class Name = CiceroUIWndFrame; Title = CiceroUIWndFrame; HWND = 65976; Pid = 3776
Class Name = THelpInsightWindowImpl; Title = HelpInsightWindow; HWND = 1577734; Pid = 4852
Class Name = THelpInsightWindowImpl; Title = HelpInsightWindow; HWND = 591660; Pid = 4852
Class Name = TTokenWindow; Title = CodeParamWindow; HWND = 985436; Pid = 4852
Class Name = TaskSwitcherWnd; Title = Přepínání úloh; HWND = 66824; Pid = 3776
Class Name = tooltips_class32; Title = ; HWND = 198982; Pid = 1768
Class Name = tooltips_class32; Title = ; HWND = 66046; Pid = 3776
Class Name = _SearchEditBoxFakeWindow; Title = ; HWND = 66024; Pid = 3776
Class Name = tooltips_class32; Title = ; HWND = 66008; Pid = 3776
Class Name = tooltips_class32; Title = ; HWND = 131538; Pid = 3776
Class Name = Desktop User Picture; Title = Magicmaster; HWND = 65982; Pid = 3776
Class Name = DV2ControlHost; Title = Nabídka Start; HWND = 65978; Pid = 3776
Class Name = tooltips_class32; Title = ; HWND = 327840; Pid = 1768
Class Name = tooltips_class32; Title = ; HWND = 460808; Pid = 1768
Class Name = CTSCTooltip; Title = ; HWND = 266710; Pid = 2792
Class Name = Auto-Suggest Dropdown; Title = ; HWND = 69884; Pid = 4732
Class Name = Auto-Suggest Dropdown; Title = ; HWND = 69802; Pid = 4732
Class Name = TaskbarNotifierClass; Title = DAP Message Center; HWND = 68924; Pid = 4732
Class Name = tooltips_class32; Title = ; HWND = 134356; Pid = 1992
Class Name = ATKOSD; Title = ATKOSD; HWND = 65884; Pid = 3636
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, start by deciding what "main" means.

Comment: Rob's right. What are you looking for. As a wild guess, I suspect you want just the windows that have buttons in the taskbar.

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144179(VS.85).aspx#Managing_Taskbar_But): The Shell creates a button on the taskbar whenever an application creates a window that isn't owned. To ensure that the window button is placed on the taskbar, create an unowned window with the WS_EX_APPWINDOW extended style.

Comment: Yeah, by "main" I mean those that can be focused through alt+tab or have icons in taskbar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The important information is contained in the [MSDN topic describing the taskbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144179%28VS.85%29.aspx#Managing_Taskbar_But). Essentially you need to enumerate the top-level windows and pick out those that are visible, unowned and have the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` window style.

This program shows you how it is done:

```
program EnumTaskbarWindows;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

function EnumWindowsProc(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  s: string;
  len: Integer;
  IsVisible, IsOwned, IsAppWindow: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;//carry on enumerating

  IsVisible := IsWindowVisible(hwnd);
  if not IsVisible then
    exit;

  IsOwned := GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER)<>0;
  if IsOwned then
    exit;

  IsAppWindow := GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) and WS_EX_APPWINDOW<>0;
  if not IsAppWindow then
    exit;
  
  len := GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
  if len = 0 then
    exit;
  SetLength(s, len);
  GetWindowText(hwnd, PChar(s), len+1);
  Writeln(s);
end;

begin
  EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc, 0);
end.
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you for the MSDN link too. I didn't know the criteria for the windows.

Comment: @David Heffernan - After a quick look I realized that unfortunately your code does not show some windows such as BSPlayer and Kaspersky KIS and Delphi.

Comment: Why not? What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: It missed Windows calculator.

Comment: I get an AV on GetWindowText.

Comment: You need a "if s = '' then EXIT" check before GetWindowText

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the properties of these windows. For instance, exclude any window that's not visible. You do this with [`GetWindowInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633516.aspx). The properties to look for: no caption (missing `WS_CAPTION` in `dwStyle`), or not visible (`WS_VISIBLE` flag). You might also want to check for windows that are moved off screen, but that's slightly tricky (there could be multiple monitors, even at negative offsets)