# How capture the handle of first window behind my form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a full-screen Form maximized and always-on-top. Behind this Form, I have another window, which can be a browser, for example. In this case, visibly the browser window is the first big window behind my Form. How can I capture the handle **only** of this window behind my Form? I suspect that some change in [this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5955728/13342561) (that uses an [`EnumWindowsProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633498(v=vs.85)) callback) can be made to achieve this goal, but how?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for the next window in Z order. GetWindow might be all you need. E.g.   `Wnd := Handle; repeat Wnd := GetWindow(Wnd, GW_HWNDNEXT); until IsWindowVisible(Wnd);`

Comment: Better check the result though, insert in the loop `if Wnd = 0 then Break;`.

Comment: The answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825595/how-to-get-the-z-order-in-windows is probably what you are really looking for.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz `Enum(Child)Windows()` is usually preferred instead of a `GetWindow()` loop. The main reason being the window list does not change during an `Enum...()` loop but it can during a `Get...()` loop. You can have an `Enum...` callback break the loop if a given condition is detected, in your example `IsWindowVisible()`